# Partitioning a list on the basis of bins where binsize is defined

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a dictionary with every key having a list of values where the keys are chromosome numbers like chr1,chr2, and the values are positions of mutations. The values are integers, and I have to bin the values in a binsize of 325. Basically I've find out how many mutations are in a region of 325bases for every chromosome.

SO the code I came up with does this:
For every key
Creates bins of size 325, starting from the min value in the value list to the max value. 
the loop through and see which position fits in which bin and print them out.

So I get the results as

```
chr8     (55655029, 55655353)    [55655353]
chr8     (55655354, 55655678)    [55655365]
chr8     (5113304, 5113628)      [5113558]
chr8     (5115579, 5115903)      [5115598]
```

This has made the first two values in different bins whereas the first two values are quite close and should be grouped together?

Do I keep sliding the bins or is there any partitioning thing I can use on the positions by partitioning them as a list, for every chromosome?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "slide bins until they fit".

Given the information you mentioned a you supposedly can directly contact!outr the bin with the standard modulo math function?